# How to Redirect from www.domain.com/folder1/postname.html to www.domain.com/folder2/postname.html?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I cannot find a solution online.

A website is currently having duplicate content in 2 folders - domain.com/news/postname.html and domain.com/news-details/postname.html.

I want to redirect traffic from /news/ to /news-details/, the link/URL of the post title is the same on both folders (ex. postname.html)

How do I do this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^news/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/news-details/%1 [R=301]
```